# intern configuration for dojo application

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dojo, intern

Intern config setup for using the project which uses dojo:

```
loaders: {
        'host-browser': 'dojo/dojo.js'
    },

    loaderOptions: {
        // Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment
        packages: [
            { name: 'todo', location: 'js/todo' },
            { name: 'dojo', location: 'dojo' },
            { name: 'dojox', location: 'dojox' },
            { name: 'dijit', location: 'dijit' }
        ]
    },
```

Here is my test case:

```
define(function(require){
  var registerSuite = require('intern!object');
  var assert = require('intern/chai!assert');
  var fooJS = require('intern/order!../../foo.js');

  registerSuite({

    'Verify Object':function(){
       assert.ok(fooJS, 'Global Foo JS object should exist');
    }

  });

});
```

The beginning of the foo.js has below 2 lines:

```
dojo.require("dojox.collections.ArrayList");
dojo.require("wc.widget.Tooltip");
```

Whenever i run intern-client i get dojo is not defined error but on removing the dojo.require from the foo.js i am able to test the function which uses dojo.lastIndexOf.

We are trying to use the same dojo which the application uses.

Is there anything wrong with configuration or with the code.

Thanks